# how to convert string type into int list

Tags: c#

I am working in an application and using a .dll file. The datatype of one of field is a string and I want to store that in a list. When I try to store it this gives me

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List"

[image: This is an error which is occuring]

```
 obj.InvoiceType = 1;
 fbrlist = obj.USIN;//(1:New, 2:Debit, 3:Credit)
 List<int> fb = new List<int>();
 fb = fbrlist;              
 obj.Items = Items();
 abc = obj;
```

this is my code actually Obj.USIn is that one which I am using from .Dll file `fbrlist` of my own variable of type dynamic. please let me know what could I do. Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds1.Tables[0].Rows)
        {               
        // start loop for multiple invoices
        Invoice obj = new Invoice();
        int POSID = 110033;         

        obj.FBRInvoiceNumber = string.Empty;
        obj.POSID = POSID;
        obj.USIN = dr["INV_NUM"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dr["INV_NUM"]) : Convert.ToString("");
        obj.DateTime = System.DateTime.Now;// "2018-11-01 00:00:00.000";
        obj.BuyerName = dr["BUY_NOM"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dr["BUY_NOM"]) : Convert.ToString("");
        obj.BuyerPhoneNumber = dr["BUY_PHO"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dr["BUY_PHO"]) : Convert.ToString("");
        obj.TotalBillAmount = dr["TOT_BIL"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDouble(dr["TOT_BIL"]) : Convert.ToDouble(0);
        obj.TotalQuantity = dr["TOT_QTY"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDouble(dr["TOT_QTY"]) : Convert.ToDouble(0);
        obj.TotalSaleValue = dr["TOT_VAL"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDouble(dr["TOT_VAL"]) : Convert.ToDouble(0);
        obj.TotalTaxCharged = dr["TOT_TAX"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDouble(dr["TOT_TAX"]) : Convert.ToDouble(0);
        obj.Discount = dr["TOT_DIS"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDouble(dr["TOT_DIS"]) : Convert.ToDouble(0);
        obj.PaymentMode = dr["PAY_MOD"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["PAY_MOD"]) : Convert.ToInt32(0);  // (1: Cash, 2: Card);            
        obj.RefUSIN = string.Empty;
        obj.InvoiceType = 1;

            fbrlist = obj.USIN;//(1:New, 2:Debit, 3:Credit)               
          List<int> fb = new List<int>();
            string inputString = fbrlist;

            string[] stringArray = inputString.Split(',');

            List<int> intList = stringArray.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
            foreach (int i in intList)
            {
                List<int> ab = intList;
            }




            obj.Items = Items();

            abc = obj;

            //ViewBag.FBR_Response = response;          
            fbr = obj.USIN;

        }
```

Here  obj.Items = Items(); is ` private List Items()//items list in parameter

```
    {
        DataSet ds2 = dblayer.gfbrdata();
        List<InvoiceItems> lst = new List<InvoiceItems>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds2.Tables[0].Rows)
        {

            // loop for multiple
            InvoiceItems objItem = new InvoiceItems();
            objItem.ItemCode = dr["ITM_COD"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dr["ITM_COD"]) : Convert.ToString("");
            objItem.ItemName = dr["ITM_DES"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dr["ITM_DES"]) : Convert.ToString("");
            objItem.PCTCode = dr["HRS_COD"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dr["HRS_COD"]) : Convert.ToString("");
            objItem.Quantity = dr["ITM_QTY"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDouble(dr["ITM_QTY"]) : Convert.ToDouble(0);
            objItem.TaxRate = dr["TAX_RAT"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["TAX_RAT"]) : Convert.ToInt32(0);
            objItem.SaleValue = dr["ITM_VAL"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDouble(dr["ITM_VAL"]) : Convert.ToDouble(0);
            objItem.Discount = 10.0;
            objItem.TaxCharged = dr["ITM_TAX"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDouble(dr["ITM_TAX"]) : Convert.ToDouble(0);
            objItem.TotalAmount = dr["TOT_AMT"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDouble(dr["TOT_AMT"]) : Convert.ToDouble(0);
            objItem.RefUSIN = string.Empty;
            objItem.InvoiceType = 1;  //(1:New, 2:Debit, 3:Credit, )
            lst.Add(objItem);
            // end loop


        }
        return lst;

    }

    //TestFbr end
}`
```

Comment: `fbrlist` is `string` variable. You can not convert it to `List<int>`

Comment: Then let me know any other way how could i store multiple data in it??

Comment: Can you share what exact value you are getting in `fbrlist`?

Comment: Data and Expected output would help!

Comment: i am getting "1234" in fbr;ist

Comment: Instead of `fb = fbrlist;` you should do `fb.Add(Convert.ToInt32(fbrlist);`

Comment: I have data in string in fbrlist. I want that my this variable fbrlist should store multiple data like 1234,1235,1236,1237 just in an array or list coz i have to assign this a number one by one in a loop. @PrashantPimpale

Comment: @MalikRizwan please add the data in the question itself! for ex: how `fbrlist` looks like and which value want to covert in the `int`

Comment: you can use `List<int> fb = fbrlist.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToList();` to get the desired result

Comment: @MalikRizwan, I added my answer below. let me know it solved your problem or not?

Comment: @MalikRizwan is your `fbrlist` looks like this *"1234,1235,1236,1237"*

Comment: @Maria thanks for your concern but it not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first split your input string with separator comma (`,`) and then convert each splitted string into integer like

```
string inputString = "1234,1235,1236,1237";

string[] stringArray = inputString.Split(',');

List<int> intList = stringArray.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();

foreach (int i in intList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: er-shoaib bro it approximately solve my problem but one thing which is worring me is that it just show the end resut which i have in que not all the list. means If i want to store 5 record coming from databse then it just store the last one  may be loop isse or something elese

Comment: could you please show how you implement my code in your side?

Comment: please check the updated question

Comment: In my db i have Inv_Num 1234 and 1235 two time now i have to assign a seprate num both of these two once respectively

Comment: ohh, i got th point, you done one mistake here, remove thses line form your code => `foreach (int i in intList)
            {
                List<int> ab = intList;
            }`

Comment: i wrote above foreach for printing purpose only, you dont need to write this in your scenario

Comment: please see the picture  which i posted now

Comment: yes i saw that. your `obj.USIN` has `49, 50, 51, 53` and it successfully converted to `List<int> intList`

Comment: But i have 1234 in obj.Usin not 49,50,51,53

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185398/discussion-between-er-shoaib-and-malik-rizwan).

Comment: let continue in above chat

Comment: love you man you make my day

Answer (score 0):

You can add the values in int list using below:

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();
List<int> intList = new List<int>();

strList.Add("1");
strList.Add("2");
strList.Add("3");

foreach(string el in strList)
{
   intList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(el));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid exception for expected values like `123y`, you can `int.TryParse`:

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();
List<int> intList = new List<int>();

strList.Add("1");
strList.Add("2");
strList.Add("3");
strList.Add("35tdfsfd");
foreach (string el in strList)
{
  int validInt;
  if (int.TryParse(el, out validInt))
  {
     intList.Add(validInt);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Prasdhant Pimpale Sir kindly check the code i update the question

Comment: In Obj.USIN i have multiple record  how could i store it in an list or array??

Comment: is it contain like `123,34,43,4` this?